# What is better helm repo to install nginx ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

As far as I understand there are two or more helm repos with nginx-ingress.

nginx-stable > https://helm.nginx.com/stable
ingress-nginx > https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

Firstly I have installed from nginx-stable, but this installation by default use selfsigned certs. When I try to investigate this question I have found out that in official tutorial https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ (which address is very similar to ingress-nginx helm repo) gives another repo https://helm.nginx.com/stable
When I have tried to generate helm templates for both these repos, I found out that result is different. Could anyone explain why there are two repos, and what distinguish between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...there are two or more helm repos with nginx-ingress`

There is only one [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) project. The helm charts referred in your question are actually 2 different projects. [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) is managed by k8s community and [kubernetes-ingress](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) is managed by Nginx (F5). Here's a [guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options/#NGINX-vs.-Kubernetes-Community-Ingress-Controller) about their differences.

Comment: Thank a lot!!! It was helpful - as far as I understand NGINX ingress controller much more complicated, I decided to use kubernetes version